# Request.QueryString returns '<%=Request.QueryString('ID')%>' issue vb.net

Tags: vb.net, request.querystring

I have an issue the Request.QueryString. When users clicks a button, the page supposed to redirect to another url with some value on it.

The current page has this url

```
http://localhost:61430/CM/cm08.aspx?ID=ABC123&PID=Y6543&APPTYPE=1
```

This is the button clicked method. I even try to store the Request.QueryString value inside a variable, and I still get '<%=Request.QueryString('ID')%>' in the 'test' variable content.

```
Protected Sub btnBack_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click, btnNo.Click

        Dim test As String = Request.QueryString("ID")
        Response.Redirect("cm02.aspx?ID=" & Request.QueryString("ID"))
End Sub
```

Anyhow, when the page loads the cm02 page, the url looks like this

```
http://localhost:61430/CM/cm02.aspx?ID=<%=Request.QueryString('ID')%>
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: put a breakpoint on that line. See if it gets to that Redirect at all. I suspect this code is not executed.

Comment: Do you also have that url embedded anywhere on the markup page?

Comment: the code is executed, I've checked with a breakpoint. I've edited my code.

Comment: What happens if you use `Response.Redirect("cm02.aspx?ID=" & test)`?

Comment: Its has the same result. I've inserted a breakpoint just to see the 'test' variable content, and it shows '<%=Request.QueryString('ID')%>'

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is not there.
Search for this string (with single quote) in your code: QueryString('ID')